# tinymce dont show the alert leaving the page

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using jquery with normal version 3.4.3.2 (non-jquery).
I am using jquery to get contents of the box like this

```
    $(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            var text = tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent();
            $(".here").html(text);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

But when i edit the content of the textarea and click submit and then leave the page.
But it shows the alert box.
I dont want it to come if the users have clicked the `.submit` after editing.
Thanks

Comment: Which alert box are you referring to? If it's the one that says 
"Are you sure you want to leave this page?

The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page."
If so, this is from the *autosave* plugin in TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post in an old topic but I tried .save() and it did not work for me either. So, I figured out a better solution that I wanted to share for the next person.

The unsaved alert is part of the autosave plugin which checks function `tinymce.get('mce1').isDirty()`. This function checks the value of `tinymce.get('mce1').isNotDirty`

A "dirty" mce is one which has unsaved changes. So, to prevent the popup you have to tell mce that it is clean without any unsaved changes.

`tinymce.get('mce1').isNotDirty  = 1;//clean mce`

That will prevent the popup when leaving/refreshing page, assuming no more edits are done to the content of mce1

Answer (score 0):

Brett seems right.

You can even use this to get the content into the form in case $(."here") ist the element you initialized the tinymce editor for:

```
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        tinymce.get('elm1').save();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: can you please post (edit your question) your tinymce init and your form html code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one editor per page try

```
tinymce.activeEditor.save();
```

See the documentation for more details
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/